# Python cv2 video resizing issue

Tags: python, opencv, resize

Im trying to resize the video to full screen but its not working? how to fix it?

```
from asyncore import loop
from distutils import command
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
from StudentDetails import *
from entry import EntryLogsSystem
from main import *
import os, sys, subprocess
from training import Training
from recognition import Recognition
from datetime import datetime
import time
from entry import *
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class home:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
        self.root.title("Face Recognition System")
        self.root.config(bg="black")

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v2.mp4')

        if (cap.isOpened()== False):
            print("Error opening video  file")
        while(cap.isOpened()): 
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                cv2.imshow('Smart Access Face Recognition Portal', frame)
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1920, 1080))
                if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            else:
                break
        cap.release()
        os.system('python loading.py')

# Resource: https://coding-engineer.com/2020/09/09/python-opencv-reading-a-video/



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = home(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

i tried this code but nothing works. i tried to resize using cv2.resize but it resize it to a specific ration not full screen even when i increase the values.

as i tried this code too but nothing worked too

class home:
def _*init*_(self, root):
self.root = root
self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
self.root.title("Face Recognition System")
self.root.config(bg="black")

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("v2.mp4")

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (3000,3000))
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

    

cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = home(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that is 24 lines of *just imports*. please review [mre] and [ask]. "nothing works" is not debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a namedWindow with fullscreen attribute, then show your image in it.

Creation of window:

```
cv2.namedWindow("winname", cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("winname", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

Displaying image:

```
cv2.imshow("winname", frame)
```

It'll automatically resize the image to your window width/height.